# Can IIS serve incremental content while the page is still loading?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am a web developer who often switches between Apache and IIS hosted projects. Over the years, I have noticed one distinct difference between these two environments.

In Apache, if I know a page is going to take a while to load, I can prioritize output so that certain parts of the screen show first. Conversely, IIS waits until the entire page is finished loading before it shows any part of it.

**Example:**

```
<?php
echo "Hello ";
sleep(5);
echo "world.";
?>
```

In Apache, the above code would display "Hello", then 5 seconds later append "world." to it. In IIS - at least with its default settings - the browser would wait for 5 seconds and then display "Hello world." all at once.

Does anybody know why this happens? More importantly, given full admin access to the server, **is there a way to force IIS to serve incremental content while it loads**?

**Things Tried So Far:**

- php.ini - output_buffering = Off
- php.ini - implicit_flush = On
- php.ini - zlib.output_compression = Off
- IIS Output Caching - .php = Prevent all caching/Prevent all caching

Comment: It is rather old school to rely on such server side behaviors, which is also browser dependent, as revealed in http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php . Please consider modern approaches such as AJAX so that your browser side code actively modifies the DOM while carrying out operations with the backend.

Comment: In most cases I agree, but not every situation is conducive to updating/rewriting an entire application. Sometimes there isn't much of a budget, but a client still, justifiably, just wants their older code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FastCGI - the most common way to run PHP in IIS - is by default configured to buffer a certain amount of data before flushing it out to the browser; so we need to disable this buffer, or set `responseBufferLimit` to 0.

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not expose this option in `FastCGI Settings`, so we must change it directly in a file called `applicationHost.config`. You can search your server's hard drive for this file, or check in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

Open this file in a text editor and search for the section starting with `<handlers`. In this section, there should be an entry for your FastCGI instance. We need to modify this entry to add `responseBufferLimit="0"` as a parameter.

**Before:**

```
<add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST", modules="FastCgiModule", scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
```

**After:**

```
<add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST", modules="FastCgiModule", scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

**Alternatively, you can use a command line:**

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config /section:handlers "/[name='PHP_via_FastCGI'].ResponseBufferLimit:0"
```

where `PHP_via_FastCGI` is the Name assigned to your PHP handler. If you aren't sure, this can be found in the IIS Manager under Handler Mappings where Path contains `*.php`.

After you have Response Buffer Limit set to 0, restart IIS. Output should now be streamed to the browser as it is being produced.